# Is there a collineation which does not preserve betweenness?

Tags: euclidean-geometry

Consider the Euclidean plane $\mathbb{R}^2$. A collineation on $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a bijective function $f$ from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that the image of every line under $f$ is also a line. Does there exist a collineation which does not preserve betweenness? That is, there exists at least one triple of distinct points $(A,B,C)$ such that $B$ is between $A$ and $C$, but $f(B)$ is not between $f(A)$ and $f(C)$.

Comment: No nondegenerate cases.  Nope.  (Degenerate:  map a line to a point.)

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Since points aren't lines, that's not a collineation.

Comment: The degenerate case is to map a line to another line of length $0$.  But if that isn't allowed, then the answer is a clear NO.

Comment: Let consider $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ subcase. Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is bijection and $f(x)$ maps $(-\infty;0]$ to $(0;1]$, $(0;1]$ to $(-\infty;0]$ and $(1;\infty)$ to $(1;\infty)$. Then for $A\in(-\infty;0]$, $B\in(0;1]$, $C\in(1;\infty)$: $B$ is between $A$ and $C$, but $f(B)$ is not between $f(A)$ and $f(C)$. But maybe this subcase cannot be extended to $\mathbb{R}^2$.